# Unicode character being escaped as plain text in simple_form with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, haml, simple-form

Because styling inputs is difficult I'm hiding the inputs in a simple_form and spoofing them with labels.

I'd like the label for the submit button to display a unicode character, but putting it in the second parameter escapes it as plain text.

With HAML:

```
= simple_form_for @post, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
        = f.file_field :file, {id: "file"}
        = f.button :submit, {id: "submit"}

        = label_tag(:file, "upload file")
        = label_tag(:submit, "&#8593")
```

Displays "upload file, &#8593"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want Rails to escape automatically, you can use `raw(stringish)` helper method.

so it should be:

```
= simple_form_for @post, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
  = f.file_field :file, {id: "file"}
  = f.button :submit, {id: "submit"}

  = label_tag(:file, "upload file")
  = label_tag(:submit, raw("&#8593"))
```

FYI, it is not recommended if the data is coming from the user's input.

Comment: Thank you. It's just a button that submits the form.

Comment: In case you want to escape the text in the `submit` button use `button_tag` [helper](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag). The code would be `button_tag "<span></span>Some text after the span".html_safe, { class: "anyclass", id: "anyid" }`